# Is it possible to fetch the github repository and branch name off commit hash in Python?

Tags: python, github

I'm looking for a way to fetch the github repository and branch name off commit hash in a Python script. I want to provide only the full commit number and I could also provide the github url (ex: https://github.com/darkxaero or https://api.github.com/darkxaero)). I want to be able to get the repository name and the branch name that the commit number belongs to.

I've tried multiple ways using libraries such as requests, Gitpython, and PyGitHub, but nothing worked with just commit number or in the case of requests library (which uses Github API url), it no longer seems to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.